# Custom directive not firing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that makes some value prices validation, and I thought that it was working well, until I notice a bug, for example if the next value price I'm validating in the input is the same of the previous one, the next one is not validated, I don't understand why, if it was different value it worked with no issues, but if the value is the same of the previous, the directive is not fired up, I have no idea if there is any relation with the '$asyncValidators', above I leave my custom directive.

Directive:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('priceValidator', priceValidator);

  priceValidator.$inject = ['$q', 'ServerValidatorService'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function priceValidator($q, ServerValidatorService) {
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        costPrice: '=',
        currentPvp: '='
      }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$asyncValidators.costPrice = function(costPrice) {
        var pvp = scope.currentPvp;

        scope.currentPrice = costPrice;

        var cost = String(costPrice).replace(",", ".");

        return ServerValidatorService.validateCostPrice(pvp, cost)
          .then(function() {
              return true;
            },
            function(response) {
              ctrl.$setDirty();
              if (response.data.errors.maximum[0])
                scope.costPrice = response.data.errors.maximum[0];
              return $q.reject(response.data.message);
            });
      };
    }
  }
})();

// Controller function that fill form with each product info:


function getMainProduct(productLine) {

  if (typeof productLine !== "undefined") {

    vm.discountId = productLine.discount_id;
    vm.discountPercentage = productLine.discount_percentage;
    vm.valuePrice = productLine.value_price;

  }

}
```

HTML

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
name="discount" ng-model="form.discPrice" 
ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 300, 'blur': 0} }" 
ng-required="formCtrl.isP()" cost-price="form.maxP" 
current-pvp="form.pvp" num-type="decimal"  
ng-change="formCtrl.check()" price-validator>
```

Comment: what does " if the next value price im validating in the input is the same of the previous one" mean?  Are you saying that you are erasing the box and then entering the same value again?  are you suggesting that you want the directive to fire again in this instance, even though the `ng-model` value didn't change?  perhaps you could show your HTML where you are using the directive to clarify what's not working right.

Comment: @Claies Basically what is happening is that in the input is being loaded different records, but some records could have the same price value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "the input is being loaded different records";  wouldn't you need an input per record?  again, showing how this is used in HTML would make this clearer.

Comment: @Claies basically i have a array of products the come from the server, and i wish to make some calculations in these products, and in my form i keep receiving these array of products one by one, after i calcualte one product the next product is loaded automataclly in the form where my directive is fired up to check. Basically is this, i already updated the post, i include the html.

Comment: how is the next product loaded automatically?  that seems to be the part that is problematic.  again, if the `ng-model` value doesn't change, then the directive isn't going to need to be re-evaluated.  You did add some HTML, but not enough that a [mcve] can be produced.

Comment: @Claies it makes sense, so since the previous ngModel value was the same in the next one, than the directive doesnt fire up, it makes totally sense, is there a work around to this issue?

Comment: there probably is a way to fix this, but it's not a problem with the directive, it's a problem with whatever code is filling the form in automatically.

Comment: @Claies i see your point, im not sure if this is the issue, but basically after one product is calculated i fire up a function that gets from a array of values and than fill up my form html. Im not sure if this helps in anything. I posted above.

Comment: You may want to "clear" the fields first, but you would also have to deal with the debounce time you have set.

Comment: @Claies i already made this, first set up in the begining of the functions the fields (vm...) to null, and i also removed the debounce, but still wouldnt fix it.